# Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with.. ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, compiling, gcc

*Hi, because my default gcc could not,
not long ago I've installed a new gcc to compile assembly files*

```
sudo apt install gcc-4.8
```

> Now, in order to command gcc-4.8 SomeProgram.s with gcc SomeProgam.s
>   I've directed my gcc to gcc-4.8 (or so I thought..)

I've used the following commands (after installing gcc-4.8):

```
$ sudo rm usr/bin/gcc
$ sudo ln -s usr/bin/gcc-4.8 /usr/bin/gcc
```

But now I get this message upon trying to get gcc to compile

```
Command 'gcc' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install gcc
```

gcc-4.8 SomeProgram.s still works.

*Upon installing gcc again I get info that implies that I already have gcc*

**But seems like I can't use it.**
So it must be a problem with the pointing.

**Please help me get my gcc back.
Please help me direct the gcc command to gcc-4.8.**

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: 1. Do not remove files which are maintained by package manager! 2. Please add output of `which gcc` and all possible subsititutions with `which gcc` followed by `<Tab>`. Also consider to install whole `build-essential` package.

Comment: Hey thank you for your comment.
Output of which gcc is black (simply nothing happens).
I already have build-essential and devtools.
Also upon commanding to install gcc I get that it's already installed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry I can't comment yet.

But I must point out that the original ln command is incorrect, which creates an incorrect relative link `usr/bin/gcc-4.8` under `/usr/bin/`

Correct command is

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/gcc-4.8 /usr/bin/gcc
```

or

```
sudo ln -s gcc-4.8 /usr/bin/gcc
```

Comment: Thanks! I've directed it correctly now and gcc Hello.s work. (it uses gcc-4.8)
How can I reinstall my previous gcc though?

Comment: I think it is still accessible, for 18.04, it's gcc-7.  Just run ls -l /usr/bin/gcc* to find your versions.

Comment: Thank you Alvin it helps me to proceed :) I still have an issue there, but with you
help I may be able to carry on!

Comment: Creating symbolic link for gcc-4.8 works! 
I dont get why in other future versions of gcc it doesn't include 'cc1' but only 'cc1plus'.